# Отображение товара в нескольких разделах каталога в Битриксе

Tags: php, битрикс

Имеются элементы с привязкой к нескольким разделам. Проблема в том, что на страничке категорий (компонент catalog.section) эти товары отображаются лишь в одном разделе, нужно также вывести его во всех привязанных к элементу разделах.

Как этого добиться? Какой параметр передать?

Comment: Вообще это должно работать по-умолчанию в стандартных шаблонах компонентов. Вы каталог отображаете через комплексный компонент?

Comment: Да, использую комплексный компонент. И да, это должно быть по умолчанию, но почему то не отображается. Хотя у товаров стоит привязка к нескольким разделам

Answer (score 0):

Это комплексный компонент, внутри него используется компонент `bitrix:catalog.section`, вот в нем попробуй указать такое значение в массиве параметров

`'SHOW_ALL_WO_SECTION' => 'Y'`

Comment: Такой параметр не помогает